# How to read ALL merge fields in msword docx using docx4java?

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j, mailmerge

I am using docx4java for getting merge fields in a msword.docx file.

my code looks like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WordprocessingMLPackage newWordMLPackage = null;
    try {
        newWordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .load(new java.io.File("d:\\ARPA.docx"));
    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        MainDocumentPart documentPart = newWordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();                 


        System.out.println(documentPart.getContent());
}
```

I am not able to get merge fields. any API we can use to get these fields?

I need all merge fileds in a list/map and i need to replace this with some other values?

my merge fields looks like `FILLIN pol_cli_fullnm \* MERGEFORMAT`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [FieldsMailMerge](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/FieldsMailMerge.java) sample.

Comment: i Am getting error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.apache.xml.serializer.ExtendedContentHandler from class org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl`
`

Comment: You'll need docx4j's dependencies, including Xalan. Any probs, please post a separate question including stack trace (it would be interesting to see, in this case). By the way, looking at your profile, it seems you rarely accept answers.  Doing so does encourage people to respond to your questions.